# EJB, exception during persist: "EntityManager must be access within a transaction"

Tags: java, transactions, ejb

I received this error: "EntityManager must be access within a transaction" what is strange for me because my bean is mark with annotation:

```
@Stateless(name = "UserControllerSession")
```

I have injected EntityManager like this:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "app")
    private EntityManager em;
```

and this is my method:

```
 @Override
    @PermitAll
    public String updateBlockedAndDeactivationReasonForIds(String userPk, String iban, List<String> associatedIds) {
        UserLocal user = em.find(UserLocal.class, Long.valueOf(userPk));
        if (user == null) {
            return ("User with id: " + userPk + " does not exist ! \n");
        }

        user.setBlocked(true);
        user.setActive(false);
        user.setDeactivationReason(DeactivationReason.DEACTIVATION_MULTIPLY_IBAN_REASON);
        user.setDeactivationDate(new Date());

        StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
        message.append(" IBAN " + iban + " is linked to multiple accounts: ");
        for (String id : associatedIds) {
            message.append(id + " ");
        }

        ContactJournalEntryBean cjb = new ContactJournalEntryBean("USER", user.getLogin(), new Date(), "Internet",
                message.toString());
        em.persist(user);
        em.persist(cjb);

        return "SUCCESS operation for user with id: " + userPk;
    }
```

As far I know default value for EJB method is Transactioanl.REQUIRED so by defualt transaction should be created. Another question is can I have 2 persists in one transaction ? Thanks for any help

Comment: You can have as many `persist` as you like!

Comment: Why do you need `em.persist(user);` for? Because the find() mthod will return an instance of `UserLocal` and this instance is managed. So changes will be saved when the method exits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the default `REQUIRED` only applies if you actually use the `@TransactionAttribute` annotation. Try adding it to your method (or class if you want it as default on all methods).